# Magento 2 module not registering and causing CLI to fail

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, cli, component

I am in the early stages of test developing a Magento 2 extension - and I am having problems with registration of the module. The confusing thing is (I think) I am following the same method that previously resulted in successful registration of the module! Also, the presence of my registration.php file is causing the Magento CLI to fail.
I am hoping somebody can spot an obvious error/issue in what I am doing - or, failing that, give me some pointers on how to troubleshoot the issue.

I am working in Magento 2.04 CE
The OS is CentOS
SELinux is set to permissive

I have placed the `composer.json` and `registration.php` files in the root directory of my module. They reside in directory app/code/vendorname/modulename. I also have a `module.xml` file in the app/code/vendorname/modulename/etc directory.

Content of the `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": “magemood/shareorder",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that shares orders with other applications",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {“Magemood\\Shareorder\\": "" },
    "files":["registration.php"]
  }
}
```

The content of `registration.php`:

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magemood_Shareorder',
    __DIR__
);
```

As well as not resulting in successful registration of the module, the presence of these files causes the Magento CLI to fall over.

> [Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException]
>   An abstract factory could not create an instance of
>   magentosetupconsolecommandmoduleuninstallcommand(alias:
>   Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleUninstallCommand).
>
> [Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException]
>   An exception was raised while creating
>   "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleUninstallCommand"; no instance
>   returned
>
> [Zend_Json_Exception]
>   Decoding failed: Syntax error

Also, if I try running something like: `php bin/magento module:status`

I get:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.

I also have the output from running these commands in verbose mode. However, I have excluded these to keep this post to a reasonable length. I can post these separately.

Any help much appreciated...

I have added some sample exception trace ..

> Exception trace:
>   () at vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:1135
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromAbstractFactory() at vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:646
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() at vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:598
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() at setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/CommandList.php:89
>   Magento\Setup\Console\CommandList->getCommands() at vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:107
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() at vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:84
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() at vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:91
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() at vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:76
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() at bin/magento:24

**Update:**
Still no luck on this issue. I am starting to wonder if there is a problem with my Composer install. Could it be Composer is looking for files in the wrong locations? I'm going to check my Composer install and review Composer documentation. Any pointers/help on this much appreciated.

Another update on the issue. I have still been unable to resolve. However, I have been able to workaround by by-passing Composer. This is OK for getting the module working for test purposes. So, it looks as though the `registration.php` and `module.xml` files were fine - and the issue lies with either my `composer.json` file... or the way I have Composer setup on my system...

Comment: Just to clarify... that entry in registration.php shown as containing a bold DIR is in fact DIR enclosed by double underscores.

Comment: it would be better if you could post you **module.xml** aswell..

Comment: module.xml:  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magemood_Shareorder" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

Comment: plz update your post with module.xml file

Comment: Please reset your file permissions and try again, the fact it says `There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.` is not okay and probably file permission related

Comment: Also you have a strange double quote in your `composer.json` near `"psr-4": {“Mage`

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error "**Decoding failed: Syntax error**" I would check the module's composer.json file. For me this has happened a couple of times due to a comma that is not needed inside the require parameters.

If your composer file has this:

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
    "magento/module-catalog": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.1.*",
},
```

You will see this error every time. Instead, remove the comma on your last required value. It should now look like this.

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
    "magento/module-catalog": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.1.*"
},
```

I haven't tested but this error would probably happen for each parameter if the last value has a comma at the end.

Comment: If this was helpful please help the community by marking it as the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth, my issue was actually due to the contents of the module.xml file. The  was using **setup_version="1.0.0"** and simply needed updated to **setup_version="2.0.0"**

Even if you're following the "[Creating a Magento admin page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html)" tutorial direct from Magento it will thrown an error if you're sporting Magento 2.2.0 and cli-enable or run setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Create `module.xml` in `etc` folder as follows :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Also verify that your module is under `app/code` directory.

Comment: Hi Deep,  Thanks for the feedback.  However, I should have clarified that I do already have a module.xml  in the format you specify in the location .../app/code/_vendorname_/_modulename_/etc       So,  it's nothing so straightforward I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

as you posted your module.xml we can see 
`xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";` having problem.

My be its by mistake or something one colon(;) is also there
remove that..

So now you full module.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magemood_Shareorder" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

in yours `http://www.` was missing & extra colon(;) need to be removed.

Also set the file permission as per [Magento official document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi - the remainder of the URL was removed by the mini-Markdown formatting of the post.  The actual URL in the module.xml file is correct.  I'm also not clear how the semi-colon turned-up in the post  There is no semi-colon in my xml file.    I'll try amending the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation parameter in line with your last post and see if that works.  I'll also double-check the permissions.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create `module.xml` file and clear `var/generation` too.
`rm -rf var/cache/*` `var/generation/*`
You can additionally do `rm -rf var/view_processed/*` and `var/page_cache/*`

Console commands do not work anymore because `var/generation` is not `regenerated` correctly.

Have permissions set right on `var/` dir (On `pub/` dir too, mostly on `pub/static`).

Or you could use console commands 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile' or 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant'. Do a `php bin/magento list` to see description or `php bin/magento setup:di:compile --help`

I assumed you're already on developer mode:
`php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`
and you could:
`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.

But if you're in production mode, clear the 4 directories above and run 1 of the 2 compile commands.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the suggestions.  Checked/done all the above and I still have the same issue.  I'm starting to wonder if there is something wrong with my Composer install.  Is it perhaps checking for files in the wrong locations?

Comment: I don't see how composer would look into other place than vendors and app/code. When you run a command with other user that doesn't have permissions in var it may say it can't see stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but if anyone else has this error using CLI :

> [Zend_Json_Exception]
>   Decoding failed: Syntax error

As MagentoMan said, it means it probably comes from an error in your `composer.json` file.

The first thing you should do is to check for JSON errors in it. To do so, [online JSON validators](https://jsonlint.com/) work great : just copy/paste the content of your file, click on validate and they tell you what's wrong in your file.

In your case, you have a issue with your double quote at the second line :

```
    "name": “magemood/shareorder"
```

You can see that you have a special double quote (`“`) instead of a regular one (`"`) before `magemood`.

Same thing further in the code :

```
    "psr-4": {“Magemood\\Shareorder\\": "" },
```

Fix this two errors and your `composer.json` should work well.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code in module.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```